# Python Pytrends proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I need to download a lot of data from Google trends using Python's Pytrends library. Can anyone suggest where I can get proxies for this? I do not mind paying. So far, I tried Crawlera and free-proxy-list but neither worked.